# Locked Phone Without Internet connection

Tags: android, android-wifi

I recently locked my phone (Samsung Galaxy S2) and I cut my WiFi and data off before it became locked. There for I can not log in to my google account. Can someone help me find a easy way to unlock it without factory reset or just find a way to cut my WiFi  or data on? I have tried pressing the home button a amount of times and calling my self and pulling down the notification bar or pressing the back button but none of these options work.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Please use other resources, such as http://android.stackexchange.com, for non-programming Android questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you USB debugging mode is 'on', you can try unlocking it via adb shell. I found this guide on googling:

http://maxoberberger.net/blog/2013/08/unlock-android-device-using-adb/

Answer (score -1):

None of the options like adb or entering null password or calling worked for my Galaxy Y. But I found this software to backup phone data like contacts,memos,schedules,etc to my pc.
http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/

Since factory reset doesnt affect your sd card, you can later transfer the backup from pc to your phone.